# How to show that the matrix $R^TCR$ is diagonal if $R$ is a rotation matrix related to $C$ in a specific way?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two matrices: $C=\begin{bmatrix}c_{11}&c_{12}\\c_{21}&c_{22}\end{bmatrix}$ and $R=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta &-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$. I would like to show that the matrix $D=R^TCR$ is diagonal if \begin{equation}\tan 2\theta=\frac{2c_{12}}{c_{11}-c_{22}}\end{equation}.

This is what I have so far.

$D=\begin{bmatrix}d_{11}&d_{12}\\d_{21}&d_{22}\end{bmatrix}$ will be diagonal if $d_{12}=d_{21}=0$. So, I calculated $d_{12}$ and $d_{21}$:

$$d_{12}=(c_{22}-c_{11})\sin\theta\cos\theta-c_{21}\sin^2\theta+c_{12}\cos^2\theta$$
$$d_{21}=(c_{22}-c_{11})\sin\theta\cos\theta+c_{21}\cos^2\theta-c_{12}\sin^2\theta$$

From $\tan2\theta=(2c_{12})/(c_{11}-c_{22})$ I have got: $$(c_{22}-c_{11})\sin\theta\cos\theta=c_{12}(\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta)$$

Then, substituting in $d_{12}$ and $d_{21}$:
$$d_{12}=(c_{12}-c_{21})\sin^2\theta$$ 
$$d_{21}=(c_{21}-c_{12})\cos^2\theta$$

I got stuck at this point. It seems that I need to posit that $c_{12}=c_{21}$, but that is not obvious from the given condition about $\tan 2\theta$. Any help?

I see that $R$ is orthogonal so $R^T=R^{-1}$. The definition of $D$ then looks a lot like a diagonalization, but I'm not sure how and if I could use that fact to proceed.

Comment: Are you certain you've stated everything correctly? (The fact that the condition on $\tan(2\theta)$ involves $c_{12}$ but not $c_{21}$ looks suspicious...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, the condition is just as I stated it. If $c_{12}=c_{21}$, then it can be derived from $\tan(2\theta)=(c_{12}+c_{21})/(c_{11}-c_{22})$. When I reversed the problem, I got that if $d_{12}=d_{21}=0$, then $c_{12}=c_{21}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false without some correction or some other hypothesis. Simple counterexample: Let $\theta =  0$, so $R=I$; in this case the claim is that if $c_{12}/(c_{11}-c_{22})=0$ then $C$ is diagonal, obvious nonsense.

**Edit:** Something I was going to add before the OP added the comment below:  It's easy to see that in general if $R^TCR$ is diagonal or even just symmetric then $C$ is  symmetric.

Comment: I take another look at the text and it seems that I missed that $C$ is a symmetric matrix, so $c_{12}=c_{21}$. If you had not pointed out that something was missing, I probably wouldn't have looked at the text again. Thanks!

Comment: @Milos So when I commented "Are you certain you've stated everything correctly?" you replied that yes, the problem was stated correctly _before_ looking carefully at the problem in the book? [frown]

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. I did look at the problem again, but missed that important detail. It happens to me sometimes. :/